# How can I get rid of the Microsoft paper clip assistant "Clippy"?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2003

Suddenly after months with, as far as I know, no changes, the paper clip assistant appears everytime I want to send an email from Outlook.

How can I kill this thing? Drowning might damage the computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Microsoft [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162763) describes how to modify or remove the Office Assistant.

From [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/419999/48078):

> Go to Add/Remove Programs, choose Office and click the Change button. You'll see the different Office features, and you want to uninstall the Office Assistant feature.

Comment: +1. I still had to do a number of searches to find out where the Assistant was, but I believe I have found how to do it. If it is gone over the next day or so, I'll accept your answer. Thanks.