# How to get rid of Clippy

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get rid of the Microsoft paper clip assistant “Clippy”?](https://superuser.com/questions/136593/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-microsoft-paper-clip-assistant-clippy)

This paperclip thing in Word is really annoying me, does anyone know how I can get rid of it? He keeps popping up when I do literally anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Add/Remove Programs, choose Office and click the Change button. You'll see the different Office features, and you want to uninstall the Office Assistant feature.